# How to save dictionary key into csv file on the same row

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary structure which contains the list of values, I need to save dictionary key alongside with lists value. I managed to save list values but I don't know how to save dictionary key to the same row in CSV file.

example of my code

```
import csv

product_dict = {}
review = 10
product_link = "www.ebay.com"
product_title = "T-shirt"
product_price = 15.99
asin_code = "A9439"
product_dict[review] = [product_link, product_title, product_price, asin_code]

#Sort dictionary in descending order    
sorted_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(product_dict.items(), reverse=True)) 
getNProducts = {k: sorted_dict[k] for k in sorted_dict.keys()[1:total_products+1]}

#Save Data to CSV File
with open("testfile", 'a') as out_file:
      writer = csv.writer("testfile.csv", dialect = 'excel')
      keys = getNProducts.keys()
      items = getNProducts.values()
      writer.writerows(items)
```

example:

[image]

So the last column "Total REviews" has to contain reviews dictionary key

Comment: Your example is not clear. Please show the example data as a complete Python dictionary (in code) and show the complete desired resulting csv file.

Comment: can you provide some code that one can paste into python and run?

Comment: updated my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solutions:

```
writer = csv.writer("testfile.csv", dialect = 'excel')
for k, v in getNProducts.iteritems():
    writer.writerow(list((k,)) + list(v))
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for